# Boxee on Dell 32in TV causes headaches, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: tv, kodi, video-streaming, boxee, iptv

I have revamped an old pc, installing 4GB ram and a [256MB video card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814187108) so that I could run Boxee to a Dell W3200 series TV that came with my apartment. It is connected via VGA, resolution is 1360x768, 24bit color, 60Htz refresh rate.

Unfortunately, every time I use it I end up with a headache after less that 30 min. I have had my eyes check recently, and am able to play xbox (connected via hdmi) on the same TV without problems.

What are the potential causes? My system seems to well meet or exceed the [min requirements for boxee](http://support.boxee.tv/forums/49598/entries/42689), XP, AMD Atholon 64 X2 Dual Core, 4GB RAM. Could it be the VGA cable? What is the most cost effective way to trouble shoot?

Answer (score 2):

Try adjusting to a different resolution.  Your eyes are straining trying to read the screen.  I find myself having the same problem at times with my setup.  I have a mac mini connected up to my 42" tv with the resolution you have at a distance of about 8 feet.  You might also be try adding some soft backlighting to the tv viewing room.  A few small led lights placed behind the tv or some 40watt bulbs diffused well could also help with the problem.